# How to use `<inheritdoc cref="...">` when one of the parameters have the `in` keyword?

Tags: c#, rider, inheritdoc

I have the following function:

```
public int Get(ref X a, ref Y b, int c, in Z d = default)
{
    ...
}
```

and an overload which I'm trying to use `<inheritdoc>` from:

```
/// <summary>
/// ...
/// <inheritdoc cref="Get(ref X, ref Y, int, Z)"/>
/// </summary>
public int Get(ref X a, int b, in Z d = default)
{
    ...
}
```

However, as is, the Rider IDE shows "Ambiguous reference: 'Get'" and cannot find the first function.

If I modify the first function's signature by removing the `in` keyword, then the IDE successfully finds the reference and displays as expected.

If I change the `inheritdoc` to use `in Z` instead of the standalone `Z`, then that part is highlighted as a syntax error.

Is it possible to use `inheritdoc` referencing a method with an `in` parameter? If so, how?

Comment: I think it's a problem of rider, because when I try it in visual studio, I can see `Get(ref X, ref Y, int, in Z)` in the candidate list.

Comment: Seems like a bug, please report it [here](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=97145)